# Simulate Post Request in Web Progressive App

Tags: angular6, service-worker

I have to create a Web Progressive App in angular 6, I created my service worker already, and also I put in cache all my get request. My problem is when I want to make a post request on offline mode because the application has to simulate the post request, so the user has to see the latest element inserted and also they can edit or delete, and when the connection is coming back I have to send all the post requests to the server and notify to the user if one post fails.

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return this.sendRequest(req, next);
}


sendRequest(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


    if (req.method === 'POST' && !navigator.onLine) {

        localStorage.setItem(req.body.email, JSON.stringify(req));
        this.router.navigateByUrl('list');

    } else {
        if (navigator.onLine) {
            localStorage.clear();
        }
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide a minimal code example.

Comment: I am using HttpInterceptor to get the post request and save it in localStorage, but I don't know how to update the service worker with the new data, any idea?